# Ajax not submitting form all the time

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, session

I'm submitting a form through ajax to a page of PHP code which will either set a session or not. This is what happens:

- Form submitted through ajax to login.php
- login.php either sets a session or not
- loginform.php is reloaded into a div on page (page itself is not reloaded (`$('#login').load('loginform.php');`)
- loginform.php checks if the session is set, then either displays log in form or log out button

.

If I log in on a fresh page it works fine.

If I'm already logged in then log out this works and the log in form is again displayed.
However if I try to log in from here this same page again the session won't be set.
I'm outputting my session in PHP and when logged out I have this:

```
Notice: Undefined index: log in...
```

When trying to log in after logging out on the same page I get this though:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: _SESSION in...
```

Any ideas?

**EDIT:
Here's some code-**

**INDEX.PHP**

```
<script language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
  $("#login_form").submit(function(event)
  { 
     $.post("login.php",{emai:$('#emai').val(),pass:$('#pass').val()} ,function(data)
     {
        //if login.php echos "no" then an error box is displayed, else it refreshes the login div to hopefully display a log out link
        if(data!='no') {$('#login').load('loginform.php');}
        if(data =='no') {$("#loginerror").show();}
     });  
  })

   //the session is destroyed in logout.php, then the form reloaded.
   $("#logout").click(function()
   {
       $.post("logout.php");
       $('#login').load('loginform.php');});
   });
</script>

</head>
<body>

<?
include ('inc/classes.php');
session_start();
?>

<div class="header">  
       <div id="login"><? include ('inc/headerlogin.php');?></div>
</div>
```

**LOGIN.PHP**

```
//just searching the database for a match and setting the session. Echos yes or no.
<?   
session_start();

include ('../inc/classes.php');
$emai=$_POST['emai'];
$pass=$_POST['pass'];

$Query="SELECT * FROM users WHERE emai ='".$emai."' AND pass='".$pass."'";
$Sel = new Database;
$Sel->nextRecord();
$Sel->Query($Query);

if ($Sel->numRows() == 1) {$_SESSION['log'] = $Sel->Record['id']; $login = "yes";}
else {$login = "no";}
echo $login;
?>
```

**LOGINFORM.PHP**

```
<?
echo $_SESSION['log']; 
//if session is set display sign out link
if(isset($_SESSION['log']))
{
?>
    <a id="logout">sign out</a>

<? } //else display form again
else
{?>    
<div id="loginerror">Wrong password</div>
<form method="post" action="" id="login_form">
   <input name="email" type="text" value="" id="emai"/>
   <input name="pass" type="password" id="pass"/>
   <input name="signin" type="submit" value="sign in" id="signbutton"/>
</form>    
<? } ?>
```

Comment: Can we see some applicable code to work with?

Comment: do you do a `session_start();` at the top of your php?

Comment: Please, add some code to your question...

Comment: are you perhaps destroying your session after logging out? Make sure you start it again in loginform.php

Comment: Hi, I've added some code. Hope that makes things a bit clearer. I am starting and destroying my sessions properly.

Answer (score 1):

first make sure that you have the html element with the id of 'login' and then secondly make sure that you place a session_start() function at the start of your PHP file